# XSLT define integer variable for use with table cells

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a simple XSLT variable setup like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="testId" select="1"/>
```

Then I try to setup the same variable conditionally like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="testId">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$var='true'"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$var='false'"><xsl:value-of select="2"/></xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

I use this variable to address some specific table cells like this `td[$testId]` (i.e. td[1], td[2]).

I don't know what I am doing wrong but with static declaration it works just fine, while dynamic declaration always returns an empty value (just td) without numbers. What is wrong with the second option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:variable name="testId" select="if ($var) then 1 else 2"/>` or, if that `$var` is really bound to a string and not a boolean value then `<xsl:variable name="testId" select="if ($var = 'true') then 1 else 2"/>`.

Your approach is flawed as it uses `xsl:value-of` which always creates a text node with the value(s) selected in the `select` expression and because your use of `<xsl:variable name="varName">... content ...</xsl:variable>` creates a document fragment node containing the content created inside.

To avoid creating a document node you can use the `as` attribute with a sequence type e.g. `<xsl:variable name="testId" as="xs:integer"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$var"><xsl:sequence select="1"/></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:sequence select="2"/></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:variable>` gives you a variable with an integer value.

The use of `select` with an `if () then .. else ..` XPath expression seems much more succinct.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, it works with both options! Also, the actual code is much shorter in this case.